Dimmer Switch Needs me to move and keeps shutting off when I'm sitting in my office - how to get it to stay on
I have a dimmer switch on my light switch at work that dims every 3 mins if I don't move in the room.  I have to wave my arms to get it to re-activate and come on.  To further complicate it, I set my printer on the desk right by it (only space left) and it's tall, so not only do I have to wave, I have to reach way around other side of printer and wave to get it to come back on.
I've tried googling and turning light off and on real quick and don't know how to turn it from dimmer to none.  I'm not tech savvy or a technician but believe I have a switch that is dimmer-only.

This isn't a home improvement question. For one, it's about your office. For another, it's about usage and not installation or maintenance. For yet another, you haven't told us anything specific about the hardware. Please see [ask], the [help], and take the [tour].

That's not a dimmer switch, it is a motion sensor switch. They are quite common in commercial buildings because without them an awful lot of lights would get left on at 5pm and stay on, without nobody making use of the light, until 9am the next morning. Even worse on weekends.
The good news is that they can often be adjusted, though it varies by model:

How long to stay on without any motion detected
How sensitive they should be to motion
How large an area should be monitored for motion

Talk to your manager or the building facilities manager. While adding or moving circuits requires an electrician, these adjustments can usually be done by anyone who knows what they are doing.

For example, in our laser labs, someone has to turn up with a passworded bluetooth app and change the settings.  Ours had to be switched to fully manual because the sensors had been placed really dumbly with respect to kit that the architects knew about.  The dimming is a warning that they're about to go off; in our case it wasn't enough to get out from under the obstructions before it went pitch dark .Options often include a much longer timeout during normal hours.

Perhaps get one of them desk fans that turns,
or you could build a periscope from mirrors so it can see over your printer.
If it's not a home office talk to your manager and/or "facilities" it's their job to make your job as easy as practical, they don't want you getting a muscle strain from reaching behind your printer.
If it is a home office move or change the switch.

Pretty well anything that moves and can fit behind the printer. Small clock, fan or drinking bird :-) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinking_bird

drinking bird is ideal because it's not only moving but also at a different temperature

Ask the building management to change the sensor to a regular switch.
Explain your situation so they know why. It isn't an unreasonable request.

As crazy as it sounds, it might be considered an unreasonable request. Asking them to adjust the sensitivity and/or timing is definitely reasonable. Why? Because with LEED certification and all kinds of similar enviro-rules, they may not be allowed to have any lights on without motion sensors/etc., with the exception of designated emergency lighting (think: exit signs, stairwells).

That would be a determination to be made by the building manager and not for us to assume here.

Present the building manager with the problem. Let them figure out the solution.
